# any hope to solve np hard problem using deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, np-hard, np, neural-networks

I know some basic machine learning and deep learning. Now a days deep learning solve many types of problem. I working working optimization problem like np, np hard problem. Is there any hope to solve np hard problem using deep learning

Comment: No, if you mean "solve exactly". Check relevant questions: https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=neural%20network%20np-hard

Comment: See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/130270/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/96778/755.